# Create two instances of the same Neo4j database

Tags: multithreading, neo4j

I have two Threads, the first one uses a crawler that collects data and creates the Neo4j graph database, the second one executes every ten minutes some queries, like how many nodes added so far in order to analyze the graph. My problem is that I can't run the second Thread while the first one is running because I can't create a new instance of the database. It returns the following error:

```
    Exception in thread "Thread-6" java.lang.RuntimeException: org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifecycleException: Component 'org.neo4j.kernel.StoreLockerLifecycleAdapter@b7c0a73' was successfully initialized, but failed to start. Please see attached cause exception.
    at com.tinkerpop.blueprints.impls.neo4j.Neo4jGraph.<init>(Neo4jGraph.java:165)
    at com.tinkerpop.blueprints.impls.neo4j.Neo4jGraph.<init>(Neo4jGraph.java:135)
    at main.AnalyzeGraph.run(AnalyzeGraph.java:28)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifecycleException: Component 'org.neo4j.kernel.StoreLockerLifecycleAdapter@b7c0a73' was successfully initialized, but failed to start. Please see attached cause exception.
    at org.neo4j.kernel.InternalAbstractGraphDatabase.run(InternalAbstractGraphDatabase.java:281)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.EmbeddedGraphDatabase.<init>(EmbeddedGraphDatabase.java:106)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.EmbeddedGraphDatabase.<init>(EmbeddedGraphDatabase.java:81)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.EmbeddedGraphDatabase.<init>(EmbeddedGraphDatabase.java:63)
    at com.tinkerpop.blueprints.impls.neo4j.Neo4jGraph.<init>(Neo4jGraph.java:155)
    ... 3 more
Caused by: org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifecycleException: Component 'org.neo4j.kernel.StoreLockerLifecycleAdapter@b7c0a73' was successfully initialized, but failed to start. Please see attached cause exception.
    at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.start(LifeSupport.java:497)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport.start(LifeSupport.java:104)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.InternalAbstractGraphDatabase.run(InternalAbstractGraphDatabase.java:259)
    ... 7 more
Caused by: org.neo4j.kernel.StoreLockException: Unable to obtain lock on store lock file: /home/sotbeis/Desktop/neo4jDB/store_lock. Please ensure no other process is using this database, and that the directory is writable (required even for read-only access)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.StoreLocker.checkLock(StoreLocker.java:79)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.StoreLockerLifecycleAdapter.start(StoreLockerLifecycleAdapter.java:40)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.start(LifeSupport.java:491)
    ... 9 more
Caused by: java.nio.channels.OverlappingFileLockException
    at sun.nio.ch.SharedFileLockTable.checkList(FileLockTable.java:255)
    at sun.nio.ch.SharedFileLockTable.add(FileLockTable.java:152)
    at sun.nio.ch.FileChannelImpl.tryLock(FileChannelImpl.java:1056)
    at java.nio.channels.FileChannel.tryLock(FileChannel.java:1154)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.nioneo.store.FileLock.getOsSpecificFileLock(FileLock.java:83)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.DefaultFileSystemAbstraction.tryLock(DefaultFileSystemAbstraction.java:83)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.StoreLocker.checkLock(StoreLocker.java:70)
    ... 11 more
```

Is there a way to fix this? Note that I cannot pass the first instance of neo4j graph database to the second thread.

I use blueprints-neo4j-graph 2.4.0.

EDIT: I use the embedded version

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're using the embedded version, I don't think it's possible to have multiple instances of the same graph DB.

Check here, although I don't really think this helps you if you can't pass in the graph DB instance into the threads: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/nosql-databases/z9nZ80ow5QY

...however, if you can, then the solution becomes fairly straight forward, e.g. singleton, etc.

Also this bit from the docs hints at the fact that you can only share an instance between multiple threads: http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/stable/tutorials-java-embedded-hello-world.html

So, based on my experience and what I keep reading, you cannot have multiple instances of Neo4j running in your application; which largely makes sense, anyway, given locking concerns and what not.

Comment: Is it possible to do as described if I use the serve version?

Comment: In that case, you're connecting via REST endpoints (unless you do everything via plugins/extensions, which is unlikely), so the same issues shouldn't occur.  In other words, you're unlikely to use the same code to connect to the server instance (e.g. via a Jersey client or another binding such as the Neo4j JDBC, Neo4j REST binding, or something like Spring Data for Neo4j.

Answer (score 0):

If you cannot share the graph instance between your threads, it probably means that you have a use case where a Neo4J server is more adapted.